# How to see the log of a currently running TFS build?

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I have a TFS MSBuild that get stuck for a long time in one of its targets. There is now update happening to build log (the indented visual log that you see when you double click of a running build in Team Explorer).

Is there another way to see the build logs.

PS. Diagnostics >> request logs will return the same content of the visual log.

Answer (score 0):

Another  is view the log through **Web Portal** (Build-Definitions-XAML-The build you are running), then click **Diagnostics** should get info as below:

[image]

If it's still contain the same content like the visual log, there is no other TFS build logs. Details you can view [Diagnose problems in your build](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635150(v=vs.120).aspx)

However, you can try to view the **Event log** in your build server to see if there are any useful information or you can use [/Log (devenv.exe)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272.aspx) to view the Visual Studio related log  to narrow down your issue.